# Excel worksheet refreshed from textbox on button click Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a code which will send a textbox value to an excel worksheet. Every time i press the button the text box value shoud replace the previous one. What i ve already done is just send this value to an excel worksheet, but in every new click there is a new Workbook opening. what should i change ?

here is the code

```
 Imports System.Data.OleDb
  Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

 Public Class Form1
Dim objApp As Excel.Application
Dim objBook As Excel._Workbook
Dim objBooks As Excel.Workbooks
Dim objSheets As Excel.Sheets
Dim objSheet As Excel._Worksheet

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Create a new instance of Excel and start a new workbook.
    objApp = New Excel.Application()
    objBooks = objApp.Workbooks
    objBook = objBooks.Add
    objSheets = objBook.Worksheets
    objSheet = objSheets(1)

    objSheet.Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Text

    'Return control of Excel to the user.
    objApp.Visible = True
    objApp.UserControl = True

    'Clean up a little.
    objSheet = Nothing
    objSheets = Nothing
    objBooks = Nothing
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't re-declare the excel objects in the subroutine. Those should be class (form) level variables. Either that or select the right book instead of adding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simplify as follows:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim objApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objCell As Excel.Range    

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    

        If objCell Is Nothing Then
            objApp = New Excel.Application()
            objCell = objApp.Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
        End If   

        objCell.Value = TextBox1.Text

        'Return control of Excel to the user.
        objApp.Visible = True
        objApp.UserControl = True    

    End Sub
End Class
```

this code should be made more robust to handle such situation as user closing Excel

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
objApp = New Excel.Application()
```

In

```
If objApp Is Nothing Then
    objApp = New Excel.Application()
End If
```

Comment: Baroooo thank you soo muchhh!! Actually your advice did the job.

Comment: It was a pleasure :)

Comment: It looks strange to me that this only change could actually do the trick, since there remains that `objBook = objBooks.Add` still adding a new workbook ...

Comment: You are right, I had tried it before post, but I had not seen that Excel created a new book over. It seems to be the same !!

Comment: yes it works perfectly.. i have also  just put the code on a timer and works perfect too. One timer change the text box value increasing by 1 every 1 sec and the other sends and refreshing the cell value !!! Perfect !!! thank you all guys !!!

Answer (score 0):

this finally  did the job

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If objApp Is Nothing Then
        objApp = New Excel.Application()
    End If
    If objBooks Is Nothing Then
        objBooks = objApp.Workbooks
    End If
    If objBook Is Nothing Then
        objBook = objBooks.Add
    End If
    If objSheets Is Nothing Then
        objSheets = objBook.Worksheets
    End If
    If objSheet Is Nothing Then
        objSheet = objSheets(1)
    End If


    objSheet.Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Text

    'Return control of Excel to the user.
    objApp.Visible = True
    objApp.UserControl = True

    'Clean up a little.
    objSheet = Nothing
    objSheets = Nothing
    objBooks = Nothing
End Sub
```

thank you all for your responses

Comment: you only need one check. furthermore the 2nd, 4th and 5th are useless since you're always setting checked objects to `Nothing` ... See my answer for the shortest needed code. And there remains the caveat should the user close Excel...

Comment: Better to use the forms load event or new function to initialize those excel object and use the form closing event to clean up assuming you are going to do something more than just that one button click.